# Memcached mass set/add stuck issue

Tags: php, bash, memcached

I am trying to make mass set/add operation from file using bash/php against memcached server v 1.4.13.
It starts normally but reaching ~1000 items (~200KB) I am seeing that script operations continues while number of memcached items still remains ~1000!
I use memcache-top and my own script to measure memcached items count.

All keys/values are unique in  input file.
I have tried to add delays between adds/sets but it still does not help!

Server flags:
/usr/bin/memcached -v -m 2048 -p 11211 -u memcache -c 16384

So my questions are:
1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How to import all of the data from file to memcached?

Output of stats while stuck:

```
STAT pid 13531
STAT uptime 31
STAT time 1364475756
STAT version 1.4.13
STAT libevent 2.0.16-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 0.200012
STAT rusage_system 0.600037
STAT curr_connections 10
STAT total_connections 5177
STAT connection_structures 12
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 0
STAT cmd_set 5135
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 0
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 777987
STAT bytes_written 68220
STAT limit_maxbytes 2147483648
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT expired_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT bytes 206141
STAT curr_items 1036
STAT total_items 1036
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topic is closed.

Dump was irrelevant and contained a lot of duplicated keys. My fault!
Anyway there is no way to make full dump of keys...

See http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/12/24/Understanding-Memcached-stats-cachedump-command